# Согласование существительного с числительным

Tags: согласование

Как правильно писать: в объеме 782 часа или 782 часов?

Answer (score 1):

Фраза семантически неясна, желательно указывать предложение полностью.

Можно предположить: **учебный материал в объёме (чего?) 782 часов**, сравнить: в объёме двух часов (Р.п.).

Здесь счетный оборот в форме Р.п., а в этом случае числительное не управляет существительным, а  **согласуется** с ним во мн.числе и Р.п.

Сравнить: объем учебного материала - 782 часа, 2 часа, числительное управляет Р.п. существительного, если сам счетный оборот стоит в форме И.-В. падежа.